# Knockout, Require, Sammy and a view model for each page – how do I make it work?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, sammy.js

I have a KO app and each of my pages has a separate view model that handles all the actions required on that page (load, add, edit, delete, etc). I've managed to split the code up into multiple modules using RequireJS, but I can't find a way for multiple view models to work at once using Sammy.

This is the setup I have in my `init.js` file at the moment, which loads the content on the first page. And it works:

```
require(['jquery', 'ko', 'sammy', 'viewmodels/page1'], function($, ko, sammy, page1) {
  var page1VM = new page1.ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(page1VM);

  var app = sammy('#wrapper', function() {
    this.get('#page1', function() {
      page1VM.loadContent();
    });

    this.get('#page2', function() {
      // do nothing yet
    });

    [...]

    this.get('#pageX', function() {
      // do nothing yet
    });
  });

  app.run('#page1');
});
```

How can I bind my other view models to the other pages?

I also tried adding a separate `ko.applyBindings` for each page inside `this.get`, which threw an error when I switched back to a page that had already applied those bindings.

Comment: You might be interested in Durandal, which is a framework that basically bundles all of these things together for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PgLgz/4/

Alright I went back into fiddle and cleaned all the code up to show you effectively what I meant by my answer -

```
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.message = "hey";
    self.page1VM = new page1VM();
    self.page2VM = new page2VM();
    var app = sammy('#wrapper', function() {
        this.get('#page1', function() {
            page1VM .loadContent();
        });
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

Remember though that in the fiddle I can't really utilize Sammy.js (I am not changing views or navigating) and there is essentially no reason to use Require.js since it is just an example, and I put all of the view models in the same JS file.

Since you are using Sammy and Require you will need to either take this code and functionally apply it to your site or post a larger bit of code somewhere.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work without the applyBindings. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Here's the page1 view model: http://snippi.com/s/jwcf5zb

Comment: Yes you do still need to apply bindings I will update answer to include that

Comment: It's throwing an "object is not a function" error for the applyBindings line.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your solution worked, but I ended up switching back to Durandal again after a previously failed attempt and it seems to be handling things more seamlessly.

Comment: Awesome you're going to love Durandal!